# Getting NullPointerException only after using saveOrUpdate method of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a controller defined like this and getting a NullPointerException Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null (full stack trace shown in the end)
only when I'm using `saveOrUpdate` method of Hibernate in `CompanyDAOHibernate`. It works fine when I just use `save()` method of hibernate. What might be the reason?

*Here's the error in short:*

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null
```

**Controller Code** below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/companyNewRecord")
public class CompanyNewRecordController {

    private CompanyManager mgr;

    public void setCompanyManager(CompanyManager companyManager) {
        this.mgr = companyManager;
    }

    // display the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(ModelAndView mav) {

        mav.setViewName("companyNewRecord");
        mav.addObject("CompanyNewRecordForm", new CompanyNewRecordForm());
        return mav;
    }

    // process the form
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView process(ModelAndView mav,
            @ModelAttribute("CompanyNewRecordForm") CompanyNewRecordForm CompanyNewRecordForm, BindingResult result)
            throws Exception {

        Company addNewCompany = new Company();
        addNewCompany.setName(CompanyNewRecordForm.getCompanyName());
        addNewCompany.setComment(CompanyNewRecordForm.getComment());
        mgr.saveCompany(addNewCompany);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

Here's my `Company` class inside `com.pending.model`:

```
public class Company implements Serializable{
    
        
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String comment;
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getComment() {
            return comment;
        }
        public void setComment(String comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        
}
```

My `Company.hbm.xml` file is also inside `com.pending.model`

`CompanyManager` interface inside `com.pending.service` is as follows:

```
public interface CompanyManager {
    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao);
    public Company getCompany(Integer id);  
    public void saveCompany(Company company);
}
```

`CompanyDAO` inside `com.pending.dao`

```
public interface CompanyDAO {

    public Company getCompany(Integer id);
    public Company saveCompany(Company company);

}
```

`CompanyDaoHibernate` in `com.pending.dao.hibernate`

public class CompanyDAOHibernate extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CompanyDAO {

```
@Override
public Company saveCompany(Company company) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(company);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Company id is: " + company.getId());
    }
    return company;
}

@Override
public Company getCompany(Integer id) {
    Company company = (Company) getHibernateTemplate().get(Company.class, id);
    if (company == null) {
        throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(Company.class, id);
    }
    return company;
}
```

`CompanyManagerImpl` in `com.pending.service.impl`

```
 public class CompanyManagerImpl implements CompanyManager {
    private CompanyDAO dao;

    public void setCompanyDAO(CompanyDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;

    }

    public void saveCompany(Company company) {
        dao.saveCompany(company);

    }

    public Company getCompany(Integer id) {

        return dao.getCompany(id);
    }

}
```

The XML file is defined inside applicationContext-hibernate.xml as follows along with other xml files (not shown below)

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryCOMPANYDB"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSourceCOMPANYDB" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                
                <value>com/pending/model/Company.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And applicationContex.xml contains the following bean :

```
<bean id="companyManager" parent="txProxyTemplateCOMPANYDB">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.pending.service.impl.CompanyManagerImpl">
                <property name="companyDAO">
                    <ref bean="companyDAO" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My SQLServer database table design is as follows:

```
Column Name    Data type   Allow Nuls
id              int        
name            varchar(30)
comment         varchar(250)    checkmarked
```

Where, id is set to primary key and is autoincremented when an insertion happens.

Here's `Company.hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.pending.model.Company" table="company">
<id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
<generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="name" />
<property name="comment" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My `servlet.xml` has this defined:

```
<bean id="companyNewRecordController"
class="com.pending.controller.CompanyNewRecordController">
    <property name="companyManager">
         <ref bean="companyManager" />
     </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:267)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:370)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:334)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:665)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.dao.hibernate.CompanyDAOHibernate.saveCompany(CompanyDAOHibernate.java:13)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.service.impl.CompanyManagerImpl.saveCompany(CompanyManagerImpl.java:16)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy64.saveCompany(Unknown Source)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.web.controller.SampleNewCompanyController.process(SampleNewCompanyController.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.security.PasswordExpirationFilter.doFilter(PasswordExpirationFilter.java:201)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.pending.model.Company.id
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:45)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5280)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4972)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:294)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:85)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:656)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:649)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:644)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.lambda$saveOrUpdate$15(HibernateTemplate.java:667)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:367)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 117 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 130 more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.id" is null
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.pending.model.Company.getId(Company.java:14)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 135 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your RestController you have this code:

```
private CompanyManager mgr;

    public void setUserManager(CompanyManager companyManager) {
        this.mgr = companyManager;
    }
```

BUT CompanyManager mgr are not decalred in this way!

you must set `@Autowired`

```
private CompanyManager mgr;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserManager(CompanyManager companyManager) {
        this.mgr = companyManager;
    }
```

And your CompanyManager must be Tagged with @Service

**Be carefull, if it is possible you can also solve this problem with JPA / JPQL.** it will be much easer for you - you dont need to write to much code.

Comment: Hi, The code I'm working with is not using annotations so I'm trying to not use it. But I have a bean defined (I've updated my code) in servlet.xml which refers to `setCompanyManager` method. I've corrected the name of the method as well. The save() works perfectly fine but I'm only having issues with saveOrUpdate() when I'm trying to create a new record. It should work like save() in this case.